Distribution agent in retry loop without message
I have a 2019 Standard publisher that acts as its own distributor, with 150-ish subscribers across the globe. There are 4 publications, of which only 2 are active. Data changes are very limited (around 5 writes per day). Subscribers are all SQL express edition.
My main issue here is that often times some distribution agent decide that it doesn't want to start properly; meaning, the job is stuck on the agent execution in a retry loop. When I look at replication monitor, the message says to look in the agent job history. The agent job history points to the replication monitor.
I tried already increasing the history and output verbosity, and output info to file, for agents that were exhibiting the problem, but it looks like that only gets started when the agent moves past the initialization phase.
Reading online I found an old article about desktop heap being exhausted but it also look like it refers to WS prior to 2016 (and I'm running WS 2019), so not sure if that really applies.
Further googling produced nothing of value. Do you know of a method to debug/troubleshoot these issues short of a ticket to MS, or some resource to try and follow?

Edit
as requested, here are a copy paste of the messages I can see:
Replication monitor:
Error messages:

Agent 'PublisherName-PublicationName-SubscriberName-AgentID' is retrying after an error. 74 retries attempted. See agent job history in the Jobs folder for more details.

Results from
SELECT jh.*FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory jh
INNER JOIN distribution1.dbo.MSdistribution_agents da
   ON da.job_id = jh.job_id
WHERE da.name = ''
ORDER BY jh.instance_id DESC

(screenshotting only the latest iteration)


"When I look at replication monitor, the message says to look in the agent job history. The agent job history points to the replication monitor." - Unfortunately this doesn't tell us much despite the information in those places being generic. Probably worth copying the full text you see (especially from the agent job history) and pasting it into your post, as there's subtle clues in there sometimes. But yea, depending on the issue, the exact error can be tough to pinpoint sometimes.

Small update, I found something in the system event view that I swear was not there before (don't tell my wife, she will say I'm just selectively blind), which directly points to the desktop heap being exhausted. Info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/database-engine/replication/sql-replication-agents-not-run
If this fixes it, I'll set it as answer.

Been a few days of monitoring and it's finally solved.
I can confirm what I said in the comment I had above - desktop heap exhaustion is still a thing on newer Windows versions; unfortunately, the monitoring steps described here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/database-engine/replication/sql-replication-agents-not-run do not work in newer windows version.
For me, the proverbial smoking gun was an information level event in the system log, with the message described in the article (Application popup: DISTRIB.exe - Application Error : The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000142). Click OK to close the application.) The event ID is 26, source Application Popup. It being information level means if you're used to focusing only on Warnings, Errors and Criticals you'll miss it.
The solution, for me, was to switch from continuous to scheduled. In my case, I went for every 10 minutes and staggered the subscriptions to minimize the chance of getting back in the original situation, but YMMV.
Hope this helps someone in the wild.
